# Why are some methods not available in Page Objects?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am using Page Objects, which are great, but I noticed that some methods, more specifically the selenium protocol methods, were not available in the `this` reference. I end up having to make a custom command as a wrapper, which works fine, but I was just wondering if there was a reason that these methods weren't available or a way to get them to become available without the wrapper methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selenium protocol methods appear under `this.api...` instead of just being under the `this` reference.